# How to enable verbose audit log in Azure Databricks using PowerShell script

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-community-edition

How to enable verbose audit log in Azure Databricks using PowerShell script.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-log-delivery?source=recommendations

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula this is manual step, I want PowerShell script for this.